# Prepros 5 with foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation-6, prepros

I am using prepros 5(latest version) and foundation 6 on windows platform. When I am compiling app.scss with libsass compiler enabled then I am getting the following error

```
file to import not found or unreadable: util/util
```

app.scss contains

```
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';
```

@import 'util/util'; is declared in _settings.scss file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen when editing/saving the util import?

Answer (score 1):

Background story: I run on a Mac but use parallels to access our blog sitting on a PC based server. Everything works fine using CodeKit but for some reason Prepros is giving me that error so I'm having a similar problem.

I changed line 42 or 43 in the **_settings.scss** file

```
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';
```

which worked, but after I did that I received the same error with the following @imports.

```
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';
```

I've wasted my day trying to figure this out but hopefully this puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. After changing the path for the 'util/util' I updated the paths for foundation and the motion-ui imports. Below is the paths I used:
_settings.scss

```
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';
```

app.scss

```
@import 'settings';
@import '../bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import '../bower_components/motion-ui/motion-ui';
```